# What file format should my fledgling animator use to create a "logo sequence" that precedes my movie?

Tags: animation

What file format (ex: GIF, mov, etc) should my graphics artist/fledgling animator use to create the logo sequence for my new movie production company, please? I submitted a storyboard of .png images to him to animate.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you'd want an uncompressed video of the animation; typically, those are wrapped in a MOV container.